# Why doesn't my modal component get the right value of props?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

The parent component has pass an integer to the child component - `<DeleteModal>`.

`<DeleteModal>` includes a button and a Modal. With clicking on the button the modal will be displayed asking for the confirmation. I've tested that the props is correctly passed to `<DeleteModal>` by print out the eventIndex when clicking on the button. However, when showing the eventIndex in the Modal it's always the smallest index (e.g. 0).

[image: Modal displayed after clicking on a button with correct eventIndex: 2]

```
<template>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-close"
    data-bs-toggle="modal"
    data-bs-target="#removeModal"
    aria-label="Remove"
    @click="test"
  ></button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="removeModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Remove Event</h5>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn-close"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
          ></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Are you sure that you want to remove this event from this csv file?
          This process cannot be resumed.
          eventIndex: {{ this.eventIndex }}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-secondary"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            @click="test"
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            @click="remove_event"
          >
            Remove
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  props: ["eventIndex"],
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log(this.eventIndex);
    },
    remove_event() {
      //...
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang=""></style>
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem . It shows the value that was provided. The question doesn't contain the code where eventIndex value is specified

Comment: Did you try without `this` like `{{ eventIndex }}`?

Comment: @Mateusz Yes. But it is still 0.

Comment: @EstusFlask the eventIndex is passed from parent component. And I've tested with the test() method that the value is correct when clicking on the first <button> (which also opens the modal)

Comment: I see. The reactivity is broken at the moment when reactive value is used in the place that's unaware of vue reactivity, which is bootstrap modal. It just uses hard-coded value in html ` eventIndex: 0`. Don't use vanilla js libs with vue, unless you want to deal with their integration at low level. There's bootstrap-vue lib that already handles this